# give a css div the default bootstrap 3 theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that I want ti give the default bootstrap background that is given to the top menu when : navbar-default .

Is there any way to do this using bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to Bootstrap 3, navbar-default- you're best off creating a new rule in your css file.

```
div.name {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```